# Select Column Names for OpenEdge-SQL

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I'm using DBeaver to connect to Open-Edge 11 database which supports SQL functions. The functions used [HERE](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/07/29/sql-server-check-column-exists-sql-server-table/) don't work. Here is a single example and the result:

Function:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'TxMSAGrading'
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [42S02]: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Table/view/synonynm "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" cannot be found. (15814)
```

How can I get column names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Column information is stored in Progress system tables called "syscolumns". Here is an example to retrieve column information of the "Customer" table:

```
select col from sysprogress.syscolumns where tbl = 'customer';
COL
--------------------------------
Address
Address2
Balance
City
Comments
Contact
Country
Credit-Limit
Cust-Num
Discount
Name
Phone
Postal-Code
Sales-Rep
State
Terms
```

List of all the system tables in Progress OpenEdge is [here](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf/overview-of-system-catalog-tables.html).

Comment: thanks @Austin!  I was able to confirm that I am connecting to the Progress system via my C# console app.  If I change that to a Select * from db.customer, it fails with a 'Table/view/synonynm "db.customer" cannot be found. (15814)'.   

Any idea why I can use your query, but when I change it to a 'Select * from customer', I get that error?